# Vue Mocha test: wrapper.setProps({}) does not update nested Components props

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, mocha.js

I am the developer of this [Vue.js Plugin](https://github.com/setaman/vue-ellipse-progress/tree/unit-tests) and am currently working on the test for v1.0.0, using already written tests for older versions with some adjustments.

### Scenario

Test the components with the following structure:

```
// receives props and passes through
VueEllipseProgress
    // receives props, adds new and passes through
   EpCircleContainer
      // receives props and do main SVG rendering
      CircleProgress
```

Use Factory function:

```js
// this is the top level VueEllipseProgress component
import Container from "../../../src/components/VueEllipseProgress.vue";
import Circle from "../../../src/components/Circle/CircleProgress.vue";

const factory = propsData => {
  return mount(Container, {
    propsData: {
      ...propsData
    }
  });
};

const wrapper = factory({...})
```

Use `wrapper.setProps()` in the test to apply new props. Test, how changed props affect the rendering of SVG elements on the other end. You can see the whole code on [GitHub](https://github.com/setaman/vue-ellipse-progress/blob/unit-tests/tests/unit/circle/circle-line.spec.js).

### Problem

`wrapper.setProps()` updates the props of the VueEllipseProgress (top level) correctly and `wrapper.vm.$props` has the expected values. But the props of CircleProgress component remain unchanged, HTML still not updated. This leads to test failures.

```js
it("do some test", () => {

      /* do some test here, all is fine */

      wrapper.setProps({ someProp}); // set new props
      wrapper.vm.someProp; // updated

      circleWrapper.vm.someProp; // still old

      // fails!!!
      expect(circleWrapper.element.getAttribute("someProp")).to.equal(someProp);
    });
```

**[Here](https://github.com/setaman/vue-ellipse-progress/blob/unit-tests/tests/unit/circle/circle-line.spec.js#L73)** are more code details related to above example.

Note, that the plugin works correctly live and all props are **reactive**.

The test worked for earlier versions of my plugin. In the meantime i have updated @vue/cli to version 4.x.x. Maybe the failures are related to this update, but I couldn't find any information in the release notes that could confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the direct solution, more a tip to avoid the problem. In my components, I use `v-binde="$props"` to propagate the props to subcomponents. However, this can cause issues with jsdom, like in my case.

I ended up with refactoring all my tests by testing each komponent directly, avoiding the need of nested structure and props propagation (like unit tests are supposed to be).